# Do Rust fat pointers consume less memory than thin pointer within vectors?

Tags: pointers, rust, vtable, dynamic-dispatch

I was reading [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8ckfdb/comment/dxfwnhz) which compares thin and fat pointers.

To be specific, the downsides of thin pointers within vectors:

> User A heap allocates each object individually and takes many thin
> pointers to them. For user A thin pointers are pretty good, since the
> vtables are stored once, and the pointers are very lightweight. Now
> consider user B, which allocates the objects of the same type on
> vectors, and never views them polymorphically, or only occasionally
> does so. User B is paying for something that it does not use.

And the upside of fat pointers within vectors:

> In Rust, one only pays this price when one actually goes ahead and
> creates a trait object. This is perfect for user B. For user A, this
> is far from perfect, since now its pointers are twice as big.

It does not make sense why fat pointers are better for User B because memory use seems to be the same or higher within vectors, not lower.

*Fat pointer cost = 2 pointers + vtable size + data size*
`(VTABLE PTR -> VTABLE, DATA PTR -> DATA)`
*Thin pointer cost = 2 pointers + vtable size + data size*
`(PTR -> [VTABLE PTR -> VTABLE, DATA])`

Given this layout, a vector of thin pointers will roughly take up `capacity * 1 pointer` in size and a vector of fat pointers will take `capacity * 2 pointers` in size. Overall required memory remains the same. What am I missing here, or is the author incorrect in his assessment?

Comment: Its hard to reason about the ramblings of a 4yr old reddit comment from a deleted user. My best guess is they are playing at the extremes: in the first example User B uses fat pointers even if they don't need them, but in the second example I think they're saying User A uses fat pointers even if they already have a vtable embedded in the object itself? I myself am not totally sure what they're point is, and depending on what it is may not be correct (or at least not demonstrated eloquently). I think they're just making conjectures on polymorphic design if users had the control to choose.

Comment: I concur with your assessment though, thin pointers (with an inner vtable) would take up the same overall space as fat pointers.

Comment: To my knowledge, fat pointers don't actually carry a vtable if you don't use trait objects. I only have a limited understanding of fat pointers in general, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple references to the same object, either via immutably borrowing or via shared ownership like `Arc`. For fat pointers, that means doubling the size of each reference. If you have lots of polymorphic references, fat pointers will use more space than thin pointers.

However, fat pointers are only used if runtime polymorphism is needed - references to concrete types use thin pointers instead, since they know the type involved. Since Rust tends to use generics more than polymorphism, fat pointers aren't used very frequently. Conversely, thin pointers require adding a hidden vtable field to every structure that may be used polymorphically, which for most code would be a waste.